# WIndows CE SDK?

Tags: windows-ce

Where can I download Windows CE SDK?

What I am trying to do specifically is create a cabinet installation file that will contain setup.dll.

Setup.dll seems to be platform specific, so I need to create it using a correct SDK (through Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario the best choice will always be to contact the manufacturer of the target device so that they give you the corresponding SDK.

If this is not possible for some reason, as workaround you could try downloading the evaluation version of [Platform Builder](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3584) corresponding to your OS, create a new OS project, select the same features you have on your device, and generating an SDK for it. However I am not sure if redistributing your application or dll under such scenario would be legal or not.